# How to mantain the Visual Studio debugger in only one thread at a time in a multithread program?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging

In a multithread application, when I create several threads, how can I keep the debugger in only one of them if they keep sleeping and waking up?
I'm using C#.

Complementing: my application needs to create some threads to control, each of them, their own (to simplify) hardware device.

Each one returns a few data from its device and it influences another thread.

To check whether one single thread is working fine, I need to "freeze" on one and check at a specific moment if it wouldn't "hurt" the others.

Comment: which vs version do you use?

Comment: Are you worried about performance, or do you want to debug just one thread? If the latter, maybe conditional breakpoints are what you seek.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can freeze the desired thread(s) directly from the debugger:

[image]